# What am I doing wrong with my macro in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXIMUM(a,b) (a>b ? a:b)
#define MAX(a,b,c) (MAXIMUM(MAXIMUM(a,b),c))
#define MINIMUM(a,b) (a<b ? a:b)
#define MIN (a,b,c) (MINIMUM(MINIMUM(a,b),c))
#define MID(a,b,c) (MAX(a,b,c)+ MIN(a,b,c))/2


int main()
{
    int a=0; int b=0; int c=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    scanf("%d",&c);
    float t = MID(a,b,c);
    printf("%f\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
left operand of comma has no operator in #define MID(a,b,c)
The expression cannot be used as a function in #define MIN
```

Comment: Why not use your compiler to see the preprocessor output? For example the flag `-E` in gcc and clang.

Comment: I've added parentheses to your macros and it expands to `float t = ((((((a)>(b) ? (a):(b)))>(c) ? (((a)>(b) ? (a):(b))):(c)))+ (a,b,c
) (((((a)<(b) ? (a):(b)))<(c) ? (((a)<(b) ? (a):(b))):(c)))(a,b,c))/2;`. Ouch

Comment: I second the pre-processor suggestion, but it's also typical to see macro parameters in parentheses to ensure the correct order of evaluation: `#define MAXIMUM(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))`

Comment: Always wrap your macro arguments in parentheses to avoid having them mis-associate.  Wrap the result as well (e.g., your `MID` macro).  E.g., instead of `#define ADD(x,y) x+y`, use `#define ADD(x,y) ((x)+(y))`

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate I am just starting with macros

Comment: Also, I hope you're doing this just to learn the C pre-processor, because this is monumentally inefficient. ;)

Comment: I have this running now, can't figure out the difference with your code...

Comment: Hello guys, I still am not able to solve my error can you actually help please

Comment: Oh, and another big no-no: The standard C libraries already define `MIN` and `MAX` macros and you're re-defining them to something else. If you want to do something like this, call them `MIN3` or something.

Comment: Note that the calculation in `MID()` is done using integer arithmetic; the integer result is then converted to the floating point representation of that integer.  You won't ever get a fractional result as it is currently written.  However, that's tangential to your current concerns — it will probably arise shortly after you solve the current problem, though.

Comment: @JamesBucanek: They do?  Which part of the [C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) defines macros `MIN` and `MAX`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, not sure it's part of the official C11 standard, but every C/C++/Objective-C environment I've ever worked in has a `MIN` and `MAX` pre-defined. Maybe the OP's environment doesn't, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: @JamesBucanek: be cautious using 'standard' when you mean 'commonly'.  Around here, 'standard' most often means "a standard as promulgated by ISO or one of its relatives".  If you'd said "Many C libraries" or "Most C libraries", you'd not get a quibble from me.  I'd not dispute they're commonly defined; they're in `<sys/param.h>` on an antique Linux box I use, but don't normally appear in the headers I routinely include.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler color me chastised ;)

Answer (score 6):

Oh! I know what your problem is:

```
#define MIN (a,b,c) (MINIMUM(MINIMUM(a,b),c))
```

should be

```
#define MIN(a,b,c) (MINIMUM(MINIMUM(a,b),c))
```

The pre-processor is whitespace sensitive; there can't be any whitespace between the `MIN` token and its parameter list `(a,b,c)`

Comment: besides please add protection for arguments a & b

Comment: explanation: using `MIN(a,b,c) ` expands to actual `(a,b,c) (MINIMUM(MINIMUM(a,b),c))(a,b,c) ` since `a`, ... exist in your code, the error is strange as hell

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Under what circumstances could you invoke `MIN(a,b,c)` and relay the arguments to other macros and have them misconstrued?  In the `MINIMUM` and `MAXIMUM` macros, the parameters should all be surrounded by parentheses to prevent misinterpration, but I'm not sure there's a way to get things misinterpreted when the macro parameters are passed as arguments to other macros (assuming the other macros are themselves safe).

Comment: I meant : using `MIN(a,b,c)` with the wrong definition just defines `MIN` as `(a,b,c) ... whatever`

Comment: the protection is necessary for `MINIMUM` and `MAXIMUM` macros, though

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with using macros the way you are.  The idea behind macros is to make coding simpler however because there are no type checks it's fraught with peril:

### Problem - No type checks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max(a,b)  ((a) > (b) ? (a):(b))
int main()
{
    int a = -1;
    unsigned int b = 2;
    printf("The max is: %d\n", max(a,b));

    return 0;
}
```

Output is rather undefined. gcc outputs `-1`

### Problem - Double evaluation

Double evaluation happens when your macro parameters are NOT simple variables, for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max(a,b)  ((a) > (b) ? (a):(b))

int main() {
     int a = 1, b = 2;
     printf("max(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, max(a, b));
     printf("max(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, max(a++, b++));
     printf("max(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, max(a, b));
     return 0;
 }
```

If you are looking at the `mid(a,b,c)` that's even worse.

### Conclusion

Please don't write code like this.

If you are sticking to a compiler where there is no *non-standard* `typeof` operator, then it's better to use stdtypes.h and stdint.h and declare functions:

```
#define __declare_min(__type) __inline__ static __type min_ ## __type(__type a, __type b) { return a < b ? a : b;  } 

__declare_min(uint32_t)
__declare_min(int64_t)
```

and you can use them explicitly:

```
int main() {
     printf("%u", min_uint32_t(3, -5));
     printf("%d", min_int64_t(-1, -5));
}
```

If you have a compiler that has a `typeof` type operator then you can use:

```
#define max(a,b) \
  ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
      typeof (b) _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

## GCC specific

If you are using a new enough version of gcc—chances are if you are using gcc, that you are—you should use `__auto_type` instead of `typeof`:

```
#define max(a,b) \
  ({ __auto_type _a = (a); \
      __auto_type _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Per gcc typeof manual page][1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html):

Using `__auto_type` instead of `typeof` has two advantages:

1. Each argument to the macro appears only once in the expansion of the
   macro. This prevents the size of the macro expansion growing
   exponentially when calls to such macros are nested inside arguments
   of such macros.
2. If the argument to the macro has variably modified
   type, it is evaluated only once when using __auto_type, but twice if
   typeof is used.

### C++

That's a whole other discussion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after MIN, it should be:

```
#define MIN(a,b,c) (MINIMUM(MINIMUM(a,b),c))
```

It works.